# How to get a Column from a Frame as a double array type in Deedle C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, deedle

I wish to extract a column from a frame as a new double array in C#.
For example:

```
double[] values = myFrame.GetColumn<double>("myColumnName");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetColumn returns Series. You just need to get series values and convert them to array. Something like that should work:

```
var arr = values.Values.ToArray();
```

or

```
var arr = values.GetAllValues().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I thought to obtain the TimeSeries and that is what I did. But it seems that there is no way to get the array directly from a Frame.